# Objective-C with JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c

1st file SSDataProvider.m:

```
- (void)getGrades: callback:(SARequestCallback)callback {
    [self personRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"grades/"] callback:callback];
}
```

2th file SSDataProvider.h:

```
- (void)getGrades: callback:(SARequestCallback)callback;
```

3th file:

```
if(appDelegate.user.community){
    [[SSDataProvider instance] getGrades: callback:^(SARequestResult *result) {
        [self stopSync];

        if(result.status == SARequestStatusOK){
            NSLog(@"Sync successful");
            [self loadWithData:result.data];
            if (deltaTime == 0) {
                [self writeDict:result.data file:@"GradesCache-0"];
            }
            [self writeDict:result.data file:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GradesCache-%@", time]];
        }else if(result.error.code > 900){
            // Show login dialog, but only if the error is a Scholica error, not a network error
            NSLog(@"Scholica error, present login view: %@", result.error.errorDescription);
            [self login:YES];
        }else{
            // Network error, so try again in a couple of seconds
            NSLog(@"Network error, will try again soon.");
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(synchronize) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
    }];
}else{
    syncing = NO;
    [appDelegate getUser];
}
```

I want grades to be fetched using an API call to /grades
But this is not working?

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'callback' but I don't know if I'm doing it the right way :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a syntax error in your `SSDataProvider` class.

You want:

**SSDataProvider.m:**

```
- (void)getGrades:(SARequestCallback)callback {
    [self personRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"grades/"] callback:callback];
}
```

**SSDataProvider.h:**

```
- (void)getGrades:(SARequestCallback)callback;
```

And then you can call it like:

```
[[SSDataProvider instance] getGrades:^(SARequestResult *result) {
    // your block implementation
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem! But why is there still no data being showed? https://gist.github.com/matthijsotterloo/26f3c5b818f3461394b1

Comment: If you have another question I suggest you post another question with appropriate details about the issue.